# Extra space before and after H1 tag

Tags: html, css

Even after reseting margin and padding the h1 tag still has mysterious unwanted gaps before and after its content

[see code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ONNged)

Adding

```
 line-height:0.7em;
```

rule approximately resolve the problem, however

1. it looks unclean
2. there are still few unwanted pixels
3. not sure that this will not cause issues with different font size or units.

Is there a clean and universal solution, maybe using sass/less mixin with math operations?

HTML:

```
<h1>Some text</h1>
```

CSS

```
* { margin:0;padding:0; }
h1 { font-size:25em; }
```

Comment: Can you post the css and a html snippet?

Comment: html: `<h1>Some text</h1>` css `* {margin:0;padding:0;} h1 { font-size:25em;}`

Comment: hi use `margin-bottom: -68px;` or  your wish the numbers

Comment: @RamanaaGj and what if i change font-size later? i'll need manualy pick approximate line-height again

Answer (score 11):

the h1 tag by default has line-heigth property you can adjust it like

```
h1 {
font-size: 25em;
line-height: 0.7em;
}
```

updated example

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
h1 {
  font-size:25em;
  line-height:0.7em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Some text</h1>
<p>lorem ispum</p>
```

Comment: that's work, yes, but again: it's unclear. why exactly 0.7em? 0.695 or 0.69 fine too. it's also doesn't reach pixel perfect

Comment: @iamjack'swastedlife  it depends on you font-size but you can adjust it like you want

Answer (score 1):

Since the `h1` is a block level element, it has whitespace on the sides by default. You can add `display: inline` to get rid of it, but it's positioning will be affected.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure, that your css rules of margin: 0; padding: 0; is on. Make it !important just for test. 
line-height: 1; should fix the problem (or line-height: 0).
You can set height for h1 element

Answer (score 0):

```
h1 {
      font-size:25em;
      background-color:pink;
      line-height:0.8;
    }
```

What you can do is just add line-height

Answer (score 0):

```css
h1.demo {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="demo">Some Text</h1>
```

Comment: use font-size same as the line-height in px.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution I had found was that, I had set a global *line-height* value which was messing with everything else. And even apart from that, I realized that just like margin and padding, there's even default line-height values to elements.

So one thing you could do is, set their ***"line-height: normal"*** or ***"line-height: initial"*** to individual elements or even just globally (latter might yield better results).

If that doesn't work, just manually enter any line-height values that seem to work for you although that's not the most optimal solution. It generally means somewhere you have a line-height setting that's overriding the same for other elements or is just messing with the spacing of other nearby elements, that share a border with it.